# Posting all inputs from a HTML form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently working on a complex page on which I have a big form with 40+ inputs. To make the form easier to fill and understand I've used Bootstrap to group the inputs into logical groups using Tabs.
However, after this, when I submit the form I receive only the inputs which are placed in the first tab (the one which is visible by default).
Any ideas why only those fields are sent and how I could send all the other inputs as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: Might be only first tab elements are inside form

Comment: please give us a demo somewhere.

Comment: is all your input and submit button in single form? if no then first do it.. then submit your form with formCollection. show your HTML

Comment: posting the code is a bit difficult as the UI is database driven, some asp.net mvc partial views are involved... I've checked the resulted HTML a few times before posting here and it seems fine (all input elements have a name, all have values...) and all input elements are inside the form element. That's why it's so weird... will check more on my side...

Comment: Copy the HTML from your web-inspector so we can have a look.

Comment: I think I may have found the issue, but I can't understand it fully at this moment. The generated page looks and behaves as expected - I have all my tabs and inputs... I can switch between the tabs, see and modify the inputs, the events attached to the inputs work fine. I can do "Inspect element" and see the generated markup for the inputs, BUT when I click view source, I see only the elements for the first tab! All the elements for the other tabs are not in the source (tested in Firefox and Chrome... I suspect IE is the same). I suspect that Bootstrap Tabs may be the cause. investigating more

Comment: ok... problem found in one of the inner partial views in which an index was generated incorrectly - we're posting back to an asp.net mvc a collection of objects and in the generation of the proper names needed for the model binder to work properly an index was getting reset causing the issue above (basically objects were "overwritten")